# Drop columns in Dataframe if more than 90% of the values in the column are 0's

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this:
[image]

As you can see the third and fourth column have a lot of 0's. I need to drop these columns if more than 90% of these values are 0.

Comment: Please post your dataset as text instead of an image. Also, show what you have already tried.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, next time please give an example dataset, not an image or copy of one. It's best to give a minimal example that reproduces your problem (it's also a good way to investigate your problem). This df, for example, will do the trick:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'a':[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    'b':[1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]})
```

Now, the previous answers help, but if you can avoid a loop, it's preferable. You can write something simpler and more concise that will do the trick:

```
df.drop(columns=df.columns[df.eq(0).mean()>0.9])
```

Let's go through it step by step:
The `df.eq(0)` returns `True` \ `False` in each cell. 
The `.mean()` method treats True as 1 and False as 0, so comparing that mean to 0.9 is what you want. 
Calling `df.columns[...]` at these places will return only those where the `>0.9` holds,
and `drop` just drops them.

Comment: I also use this the above syntax for True/False columns as well. `df.columns[((df==True).mean()>0.95)]`. Super clean & Pythonic answer!

Comment: @kevin_theinfinityfund Do you need `df==True` for boolean columns? Can't you just take the mean? After all, for a boolean column, `df==True` will return the same values...

Comment: You don’t. I was being explicit by showing my columns are already true/false values, mimicking your syntax, but you’re definitely right. I thought it provided readability for myself later on, “Oh the df I’m manipulating is already comprised of all True/False.”

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick for you:

```
row_count = df.shape[0]
columns_to_drop = []

for column, count in df.apply(lambda column: (column == 0).sum()).iteritems():
    if count / row_count >= 0.9:
        columns_to_drop.append(column)

df = df.drop(columns_to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bad_col = []
for i, x in enumerate(df.columns):
    if sorted(list(df[x].value_counts(normalize = True).values))[-1] >= 0.9 :
        bad_col.append(x)
```

Comment: Hi Mohamed  Code-only answers are discouraged (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) and [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)). Good answers tend to have some explanation and some code.

Answer (score -1):

Explanation inline the code    .

```
#Suppose df is your DataFrame then execute the following code.

df_float=df.loc[:, df.dtypes == np.float64] #checks if the column contains numbers

for i in df_float.columns:
    if ((len(df_float[i].loc[df_float[i]==0])/len(df_float))>0.9): #checking if 90% data is zero
        df_float.drop(i,axis=1,inplace=True) #delete the column

#Your results are stored in df_float
```